# Calculate difference of two columns and output result in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag, difference

Goal - Trying to calculate the difference between months based on two criteria, row number and Person ID.

I'm not sure how to get the difference

The Month Difference should be calculated based on the person ID and the row number,

higher the rownumber means the largest month value

Here is the data in [rextester](https://rextester.com/YENAA48296).

Current Data

[image: Current Data]

Result

[image: Result]

Comment: Please update your question and add to the description, the db schema, data, Queries you have tried and expected results . See:  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You should post data as text instead of images. And what is the result image here? Is that what you want as output?

Comment: Als@SeanLange - op needs more SO points to do that AFAIK. I did it for him. Also will you always have consecutive months in your data. 1, 3 and 4 - what do you do then - is diff between month 3 and 1 invalid.

Comment: I have added this [SQL](https://rextester.com/YENAA48296) for others to play with. Works better than images...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `lag()` does what you want:

```
select rownum, personid, month,
       (month -
        lag(month) over (partition by personid order by month)
       ) as diff
from t;
```

Note that for the first row, `diff` will be `NULL` rather than `'First Time'`.

You can test it [here](https://rextester.com/QTI76379).

Comment: Really great answer. Learnt something new there. Added a link for SQL too. So OP can run it to see it's correct.

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice. I'm quite new to Stack Overflow. Not entirely sure what information is helpful to use and what isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to steal Gordon's thunder here, because he did the hard part.

Here's the extra [bit](https://rextester.com/JHSA75316) converting NULL to 'First Time'.

```
create table #pivottabledata(Rownum int, PersonId int, Month int);
insert into #pivottabledata values(1,123,1);
insert into #pivottabledata values(2,123,2);
insert into #pivottabledata values(3,123,4);
insert into #pivottabledata values(4,123,5);
insert into #pivottabledata values(5,123,12);
insert into #pivottabledata values(1,222,1);
insert into #pivottabledata values(2,222,3);
insert into #pivottabledata values(3,222,4);
select * from #pivottabledata;
with cte (rownum,personid,month,diff) AS
(
select rownum, personid, month,
       (month -
        lag(month) over (partition by personid order by month)
       ) as diff
from #pivottabledata
)
SELECT rownum personid, month, 
       ISNULL(CAST(diff AS VARCHAR(max)), 'First Time') as diff
from cte;
```